# App Engine application over quota due to datastore not available in the project

Tags: google-app-engine

My App Engine application is over quota due to datastore not available in the project. My golang code regularly checks if datastore is available as point of reference for overquota or system critical issue. I am a billed project owner. When I clicked my Datastore console and Indexes and got this error details:

```
Server Error
There's a problem at our end.
Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using the "Send feedback" link below. Thanks!

Tracking Number: 6514405077127508084
```

Is there an ongoing issue or maintenance with Google Appengine / Datastore?

Thanks,
Edwin

Answer (score 0):

The message indicates indeed a problem on the Google side.

But the fact that the occurrence is automatically tracked indicates an accidental incident caught by the infrastructure monitoring system (so not *entirely* unexpected). Most likely a transitory one - the issue *should* be resolved either automatically, if the infra has a corresponding self-healing solution implemented for that particular case, or with Google SRE team's intervention.

There shouldn't be anything you need to do, unless the issue persists (as the message indicates).

Normally the regular maintenance activities would not cause such events, they should be entirely transparent for the end-user apps. And IMHO it wouldn't make a lot of sense to specifically track every occurence for known non-transient ongoing issues.